# unable to use MIN and IF function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Age   Qualification**

19  Higher Secondary School

24  Graduate

25  Post Graduate or above

21  Graduate

17  Higher Secondary School

I am trying to get Minimum age of graduate student which is 21. The incorrect formula i used is **=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$6="Graduate",$A$2:$A$6))**
which gives 17 as min value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula itself is ok, but you need to enter it as an array formula (press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when you entered it instead of simple ENTER)